# Android - Update Google Play through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-services

As I'm using the GPS in my App and am using the Google Play Services in this purpose, I always check if they are up to date. Is there a way to make it easy to the user to update it? Like a kind of intenet?
I've already the code checking if the services are up to date and poping up a message if they re not, i just want to make it a no brainer for the user.
Thanks beforehand =)

Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I always check if they are up to date. Is there a way to make it easy
>   to the user to update it

[SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED) constant is available which return by `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` when *The installed version of Google Play services is out of date*

Use  `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED` constant value to show Error alert using `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog` to request user for updating available service version:

```
int responseCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(responseCode, activity, 0);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you =)